# How to persist state of a Jetbrains Teamcity server instance in a docker image to deploy to others without my local directory volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, teamcity, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to create an image of a docker container of my teamcity server instance so that if I were to run that image, all of the build configurations and everything would be automatically on it.

Currently I am using the command line from the docker hub and using volumes to connect to my local machine directory which works. However, this uses my local file directory and I am trying to have it so I can deploy it to other users and have all of the configurations saved in the container image so they don't need to download the files locally.

I have done docker commit of what seemed like it should work as I docker exec inside the container and saw the files that needed to be saved, but when I run it, they're gone.

I've also tried to docker cp the files over which worked fine, but again committing it and running the new container image results in a blank directory.

I have a docker-compose like this:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  server:
    image: jetbrains/teamcity-server
    ports:
      - "8111:8111"
    volumes:
      - C:/ProgramData/JetBrains/TeamCity:C:/ProgramData/JetBrains/TeamCity
      - C:/TeamCity/logs:C:/TeamCity/logs
    mem_limit: 2g
```

That works fine and loads the configs and what not perfectly fine. But then I do:

```
docker stop [container_name]
```

then:

```
docker commit [container_name] [image]
```

then then when I try to run it, Teamcity comes up as if I had left the volumes blank. When I exec into it, there are no folders like in the original container that I committed.

Comment: Can you provide the code that you tried?

Comment: @mkemmerz added